# How to create a toggle right click macro?

Tags: mouse

I've been trying to play MGSV (Metal Gear Solid 5) via Geforce Now but sadly it doesn't have a built-in toggle aim option. I also tried to use controllermate but to no avail, I can't seem to do it or find a guide to do it. Does any one know a way, via a macro or any other means, to make it so that if I click the Right Mouse Button it would toggle even without an in game option?

Comment: What is MGSV, that at least, may help some of us.

Comment: Metal Gear Solid V, I'm guessing. Probably more a question for https://gaming.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Yeah, Metal Gear Solid 5. I assume that the question would be better posted here due to it being more about the peripheral device of an Apple iMac rather than the gaming section.